# Prove $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}\right)=\frac{π}{4}+\frac{i}{2}{\ln}\frac{x+y}{x-y}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have nearly proved the question but I have stucked on a step 
$$2a = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}\right)$$

$$2a =  \tan^{-1}\left[\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}\right)\right)\right]$$

Comment: Enclose your mathematical formulas in dollar signs, so that they will show correctly. Read here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

HINT, we can use Euler's formula:

$$e^{\theta i}=\cos\left(\theta\right)+\sin\left(\theta\right)i\tag1$$

We also know that:

- $$2i\sin\left(\theta\right)=e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}\tag2$$
- $$2\cos\left(\theta\right)=e^{\theta i}+e^{-\theta i}\tag3$$

Dividing equation $(2)$ by $(3)$ and then dividing both sides by $i$ results in:

$$\tan\left(\theta\right)=\frac{1}{i}\left(\frac{e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}{e^{\theta i}+e^{-\theta i}}\right)\tag4$$

Let $\text{z}=\theta\in\mathbb{C}$, so that:

$$\tan\left(\text{z}\right)=\frac{1}{i}\left(\frac{e^{\text{z}i}-e^{-\text{z}i}}{e^{\text{z}i}+e^{-\text{z}i}}\right)\tag5$$

Now, using Euler's formula again:

$$e^{\text{z}i}=\exp\left(-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)\right)\cdot\exp\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)i\right)=\exp\left(-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)\right)\cdot\left(\cos\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\right)+\sin\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\right)i\right)\tag6$$